# Raspberry pi and Pygame Menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pygame

I wanted to use a library in python called pygame-menu in raspberry pi because I wanted to develop a game with somebody else. I tested one of their demos and I got the following error:

```
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Pandemic/GameDev.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pygame_menu
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygame_menu/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    import pygame_menu.themes
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygame_menu/themes.py", line 386, in <module>
    THEME_DEFAULT = Theme()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygame_menu/themes.py", line 198, in __init__
    bool, pygame.vernum.major == 2)  # type: bool
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major'
```

Here is also my code:

```
import pygame
import pygame_menu
pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
def set_difficulty(value, difficulty):
    # Do the job here !
    pass

def start_the_game():
    # Do the job here !
    pass
menu = pygame_menu.Menu(300, 400, 'Welcome',
                       theme=pygame_menu.themes.THEME_SOLARIZED)

menu.add_text_input('Name :', default='John Doe')
menu.add_selector('Difficulty :', [('Hard', 1), ('Easy', 2)], onchange=set_difficulty)
menu.add_button('Play', start_the_game)
menu.add_button('Quit', pygame_menu.events.EXIT)
menu.mainloop(surface)
```

Can you please help me fix it I ran the program with Thonny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. It turns out the raspberry pi has a default version of 1.9.4 of pygame and pygame-menu required 1.9.6 and above so I upgraded it with this command:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the error comes from the pygame_menu library. You should check the compatibility between `pygame_menu` and `pygame` version. The last version of `pygame-menu` require `pygame 1.9.6` or more.

Comment: The thing is that I did on my laptop and it worked perfectly...

Comment: Are there differences between your environments like the python version or the os ? And can you show the dependency with `pip freeze` for both computers ?